# Bitachon vs emunah

Tags: faith-bitachon-emunah

I tried to find the answers to these questions on Google but I couldn't get a definitive answer.

1. What is the definition of emunah?
2. What is the definition of bitachon?

Comment: You will get lots. I like this one: emuna is the belief that Hashem runs the world, and everything He does is ultimately for the good. Bitachon is the trust that Hashem will do for me personally revealed good

Comment: https://archive.org/details/ravavigdormiller0000mill/page/308/mode/2up There’s a chapter in this book by Rav Avigdor that speaks about it. Somewhere early on

Comment: I would say that emunah means belief in HaShem's existence and bitachon means belief in reward and punishment

Comment: @RabbiKaii Presumably the definitions will correlate with the scope of hashgacha one subscribes to

Comment: @Nahum eilu v'eilu

Comment: Emunah is faith, belief in something specific. Bitachon is trust, a diffuse non-specific confidence.

Answer (score 2):

Bitachon is a powerful sense of **optimism** and **confidence** based not on reason or experience But on emunah. when you have bitachon you have no fears or frets with bitachon. You will always be able to point out the positive side of life's experiences. **It's the awareness that everything that happens is all for the good**. Everything right now is good **even when it superficially looks terrible**. God will bless you in whatever you do and therefore, **it's not your own smarts or hard work that will provide success But God's blessing is what makes a man rich**. God does Whatever he wants. help can only come from God. when I'm in trouble I should first take care of spiritual matters. I.e. Prayer, repentance, kindness and charity.

Source: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1405289/jewish/Bitachon.htm

**Emunah is the clear understanding that Hashem runs the world, from big to little, from global to local, across all platforms and situations. Hashem is there controlling every outcome.**

emunah is the knowledge that Hashem is involved in the minutiae of my daily life. Hashem is there with me, 24/7, 365, all day, every day, from morning to night. No human being or other power can change my destiny. Hashem decrees the fate of man, and Hashem is there on the scene to carry out that decree.

Emunah is the understanding that Hashem is involved in the big picture issues. Life and death. War and famine. Disease and disaster. Which countries will go to war? Which will enjoy peace? Which economies will expand? Which will collapse?

The Rambam defines emunah as the knowledge that Hashem created and continues to run all of Creation.

Simply put, nothing can exist and no activity can occur without Hashem.

Source: https://www.ou.org/life/inspiration/difference-emunah-bitachon/